# Remove rows when the occurrence of a column value in the data frame is less than a certain number using pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1    col2
A         1
B         1
C         2
D         3
D         2
B         1
D         5
```

I have seen that col1 values with B and D occurs more than one times in the data frame.

I want to keep those values with occurrence more than one, the final data frame will look like:

```
col1     col2
 B         1
 D         3
 D         2
 B         1
 D         5
```

How to do this in most efficient way using pandas/python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with specify column `col1` for search dupes with `keep=False` for return `True`s for all dupe rows, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated('col1', keep=False)]
print (df)
  col1  col2
1    B     1
3    D     3
4    D     2
5    B     1
6    D     5
```

If need specify threshold use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` and filter same way like first solution:

```
df = df[df.groupby('col1')['col1'].transform('size') > 1]
print (df)
  col1  col2
1    B     1
3    D     3
4    D     2
5    B     1
6    D     5
```

Alternative solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df[df['col1'].map(df['col1'].value_counts()) > 1]
```

If performance is not important use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('col1').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) setting `keep=False`, which will return `True` for all duplicate values in `col1`, and then simply use [boolean indexation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html) on the dataframe:

```
df[df.col1.duplicated(keep=False)]

   col1  col2
1    B     1
3    D     3
4    D     2
5    B     1
6    D     5
```

---

**Update**

For keeping values where `col1` occures more than `thr` times, use:

```
thr = 2
df[df.col1.duplicated(keep=False).groupby(df.col1).transform('sum').gt(thr)]

   col1  col2
3    D     3
4    D     2
6    D     5
```

Comment: what if I want to keep those where it occurs more then 2 times, lets suppose what will be for n times ?